# Onblur/onfocus not working inside php

Tags: php, onblur, onfocus

I'm trying to add onfocus/onblur events to a form, but somehow I'm not getting it to work. I think it has to do with escaping the quotes, but I've tried several ways with no success. My code is this:

```
    echo '<input type="password" id="'.$field->name.'" name="'.$field->name.'" size="30" class="inputbox" placeholder="'.$field->title.'"
                onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = '.$field->title.'"
                />'."\n";
                break;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing quotes around your onblur string:

```
<?php
echo '<input type="password" id="' . $field->name . '" name="' . $field->name . '" size="30" class="inputbox" placeholder="' . $field->title . '" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = \'' . $field->title . '\'" />'."\n";
```

Comment: I had to escape also the single quotes on onfocus... but overall your help solved my problem.